# guava-libraries: List with n instances

Tags: java, guava, utility-method

The Java `Collections` class has the following method:

```
static <T> List<T> nCopies(int n, T o)
```

I need a similar method, but slightly more generic, which provides *n* instances of a given class. Something like:

```
static <T> List<T> nInstances(int n, Supplier<T> supplier)
```

In particular, if `supplier` is `Supplier.ofInstance(o)`, we get the same behavior as the `nCopies()` method. Is there such a method somewhere in the Guava API?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, but it's easy enough to implement:

```
public static <T> List<T> nInstances(int n, Supplier<T> supplier){
    List<T> list = Lists.newArrayListWithCapacity(n);
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        list.add(supplier.get());
    }
    return list;
}
```

Comment: I don't think that can really be considered equivalent to `Collections.nCopies`, since the distinguishing thing about that is that the `List` it returns uses minimal storage (just an int and one reference). This just dumps all the values returned by the supplier into an `ArrayList`.

Comment: Sure, it's easy enough. In fact I have already implemented exactly what you propose.

Comment: @ColinD no, it's not equivalent, obviously (and it's definitely not Guava-worthy). But it does what the OP wanted

Comment: Yeah, though he wasn't very clear on what he actually wanted. The more I think about it though, the more I think that something equivalent to `Collections.nCopies` that calls a `Supplier` for each `get` would be a terrible, terrible idea unless it cached each value... so this is probably best.

Answer (score 4):

No there isn't, and any equivalent construct (that just stores the int n and the supplier and calls the supplier for each `get`) seems like a terrible idea. That said, apparently you just want to read n objects from a `Supplier` and store them in a list. In that case, Sean's answer is probably best.

Just for fun though, here's another way you could create an `ImmutableList` of size n by calling a `Supplier` n times (`transform`, `limit` and `cycle` all from `Iterables`):

```
public static <T> ImmutableList<T> nInstances(int n, Supplier<T> supplier) {
  return ImmutableList.copyOf(transform(
      limit(cycle(supplier), n), Suppliers.<T>supplierFunction()));
}
```

I uh... wouldn't recommend this over a straightforward loop implementation though (for readability reasons mostly).

Comment: Here is another fun one line approach: 

transform(limit(cycle(1), copyCount), Functions.forSupplier(supplier))

Answer (score 3):

Like many other idioms, Java 8 finally delivers with a short and sweet version that doesn't need any external libraries. You can now do this with [`Streams.generate(Supplier<T> s)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#generate-java.util.function.Supplier-). For example, for `n` instances of `Foo`:

```
Streams.generate(Foo::new).limit(n)...
```

You'd finish that line off in different ways depending on how you wanted to create your List. For example, for an `ImmutableList`:

```
ImmutableList.copyOf(Streams.generate(Foo::new).limit(n).iterator());
```